# add functionality to every function call

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of legacy crappy code... There is a bug in the middle of that code. Prototype library method is called with incorrect arguments, somewhere is this pile of...

I thought it would be possible to add

```
console.log( _name_of_calling_function );
```

to every function call on the page, so that it would be easier to find the bug.
After some searching I came up with:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
__protoCall = Function.prototype.call;
Function.prototype.call = (function()
{
    var cached = __protoCall;
    return function()
    {
        console.log(arguments.callee.name);
        cached.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}());
```

I can see that the function is executed, however the arguments.callee.name is empty :/

Please help.

Comment: You seem to be looking for `arguments.callee.caller.name` - the `callee` is your anonymous function. But regardless, you'd better go with `debugger;` or `console.trace();`

Comment: arguments.callee is deprecated, you should not use it